# Recursively include Nuget DLLs via Gitignore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, nuget, gitignore

I am using GIT with a new ASP.NET MVC project. I have a line in my gitignore file to ignore dlls

```
*.dll
```

I would like to add something along the lines of the following to include (i.e. do not ignore) DLLs in my NUGET packages folder

```
  !/packages/*.dll
```

The problem I'm encountering is that not all nuget packages are created equally and, depending on the package in question, DLLs may be nested an arbitrary number of levels in the path hierarchy. It seems that I simply need a recursive solution along the lines of:

```
!/packages/**/*.dll

!/packages/**/*
```

I have not yet found a solution that will work via mysysgit (or any windows distribution of git).

Does anyone know of a way to make this work???

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Leave your top level `gitignore` alone by keeping `*.dll` in it.

Create another `.gitignore` file in the packages directory and put `!*.dll` in it.

Answer (score 9):

Another option to consider is NOT including your NuGet dlls in your repository and instead only download them the first time you build your project. This is what we do with all of our NuGet dependencies.

**UPDATE**

Nuget handles this now without having to manually create your own build events. See the details on this page: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

---

**Original Answer:**

We put the NuGet.exe application in a tools folder under our solution, and then add the following to our project pre-build event.

```
"$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" install "$(ProjectDir)packages.config" -o "$(SolutionDir)Packages"
```

The first time we build the app it will download all of the dependencies, but with subsequent builds, NuGet is smart enough to see that they already exist at the correct version and skips them.

Comment: That's an interesting solution - what problems does it solve for you?

Comment: I guess I see it as an extension of not checking in generated code. We were having a number of issues with our Service References being checked in and while fixing that issue, we also got rid of as many external dependencies in our repo as possible. We had issues at the time with largish binary files slowing down our checkouts in SVN. I'm not sure that would be an issue with our current setup, but we haven't gone back.

Comment: Update: Nuget supports this OOB with Nuget Package Restore.

Comment: Interesting idea and see the point to a degree, but for automated builds, and ensuring the external assemblies exist for future (ie if a build is not executed for a long time) you may want the actual files you tested with or have them available during the build process without relying on nuget availability.