# Sharing my dll libraries across projects in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, workflow, shared-libraries

What is the best way to share dll libraries between projects, through VS2010? For example we have made a generic helper library that is useful in everything. However, we need more than one library to be included (which is a separate project in TFS) so branching is not suitable.

We are using Team Foundation Server 2010 for source control. Is there maybe a simple way to integrate these libraries into a new project, so the new project can come "fully buffed" very fast?

What we do now is go through each project, build them, store the dll files, add a new project then throw them in the Bin folder, which is tedious work when you have many libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is some TFS-based solution for sharing binaries between projects. However you can use NuGet to do it for you. Create nuget package for each project (you can create TFS build definition to do it automatically) and publish it to network share. Than add this share as NuGet feed.

Comment: Thank you! Actually this is exactly what I was going to edit to: If we can use the nuget paradigm for our own libraries... Great!

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought about [hosting your own NuGet feed](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/10/21/hosting-your-own-local-and-remote-nupack-feeds.aspx)? I use a [pre-build script for NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7376151/171703) for each of my projects which downloads packages for me before the project is built, and, I assume, keeps them up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'm going with this solution as also pointed above